# Difference between register/subscribe call/publish

Tags: autobahn, crossbar, thruway

I'm learning WAMP (Web Application Messaging Protocol ). I'm trying to figure out the difference between these methods in AutobahnJS.
( and PHP Client with Thruway - https://github.com/voryx/Thruway)

- register/subscribe
- call/publish

But I can't get the difference between them, any tips?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite library you use, WAMP define:

> **Message**

1. For sending **messages** (can be objects also) without response to one or more clients use **subscribe/publish**.

   1. To form a group/room/communication pool/newspaper defined by topic, every client must first **subscribe** to that topic.
   2. To notice every listener of topic (subscribers), publisher **publish**es message. As result publisher only receives a callback publish Ok or publish failed.

> **Service**

2. For offering some "**service**" on one side, like providing math operation, or discover your current GPS location, and to use those services on the other side, use **register/call** remote procedure call (RPC). A service will return some response to caller only.

   1. Provider first must **register** service to allow clients to use it.
   2. To use service, client must make an RPC **call**, with or without parameters and it will receive results from the service.

> Note: Service and Message are probably not totally correct terms here.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at the "A quick introduction to WAMP" presentation on the [WAMP homepage](http://wamp.ws/), the WAMP FAQ ([here](http://wamp.ws/faq/#rpc) and [here](http://wamp.ws/faq/#pubsub)) or the figures in the section "How it works" on the [Crossbar.io homepage](http://crossbar.io/).